# PivotProtocol in vapor

Tags: vapor

How to make a Pivot with the same objects? 
I have this tried but get an mySQL error:

```
final class UserParent: Model, PivotProtocol {
    var storage = Storage()

    typealias Left = User
    typealias Right = User

    static var leftIdKey: String = "user_id_parent"
    static var rightIdKey: String = "user_id_child"

    init(row: Row) throws { }

    func makeRow() throws -> Row {
        let row = Row()
        return row
    }

}

//MARK: - Preparation
extension UserParent: Preparation {
    static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
        try database.create(self, closure: { builder in
            builder.id()
            builder.int("user_id_parent")
            builder.int("user_id_child")
        })
    }

    static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
        try database.delete(self)
    }
}
```

and then i have this on my user object

```
var users: Siblings<User, User, UserParent> {
    return siblings()
}
```

but I get this mySQL error

```
[MySQL Error: Unknown column 'user_parents.user_id' in 'where clause']
```

Comment: The ability to create custom keys was added in this PR: https://github.com/vapor/fluent/pull/251 Check out the tests for it here: https://github.com/vapor/fluent/pull/251/files#diff-b6a7113811c9efca25dcc7e0067dafaaR2

Answer (score 0):

To complete tanner0101's answer:

Your model is correct, but your `Siblings` implementation must specify the custom keys as well.

```
var parentUsers: Siblings<User, User, UserParent> {
  return siblings(localIdKey: "user_id_child", foreignIdKey: "user_id_parent")
}
var childUsers: Siblings<User, User, UserParent> {
  return siblings(localIdKey: "user_id_parent", foreignIdKey: "user_id_child")
}
```